# fans spinning up and can't find the issue

Tags: finder, imac, hardware

Fans have been spinning up and then spinning down recently. I have made some changes including two hardware changes, and I am hesitant to mention it because we will all go there, I have recently added a non Apple SSD to my iMac (I am glad I opened it up - the fan was filled with dust) I have also added a Thunderbolt Ethernet 10G adapter.

To Rule out hardware issues. I have run an Apple Hardware Test and it came back with flying colors:

[image]

I reset PRAM, the SMC, rebooted in SAFE mode, and eventually reinstalled macOS.

I then went on to troubleshooting tools (TinkerTool, MacPilot) to remove caches, etc.

Finally, I ran `defaults delete com.apple.finder`

None of this has had an effect on the messages in the console or the fans random spinning up.

Looking in Console is a dangerous thing to do... since latest boot I have over 4000 messages like this;

> cfprefsd Couldn't open parent path due to [2: No such file or directory]

[image: Couldn't open parent path due to]

How can the system not know where the defaults are for Finder or not be able to open them.

Looking in Activity Viewer

Comment: Did you replace a HDD with a SSD? If so, what did you do about the temperature sensor?

Comment: @Gilby I replaced an Apple 512 MB SSD with a Samsung 1TB 980 Pro using a well regarded adapter. I guess I could remove it and see if the issue persists - it's the boot device though. I am wondering if during the process the 4 year old thermal paste on the processor may have lost good contact.

Comment: You need to say what model of Mac and what "well regarded" adapter. Otherwise go to https://www.ifixit.com and look at the instructions for your Mac.

Comment: @Gilby [2019 iMac] [SAMSUNG 980 PRO SSD 1TB PCIe 4.0 NVMe Gen 4] [Sintech NGFF M.2 nVME SSD Adapter]. Your source of information is ifixit.com?

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/308179/after-re-assembly-imac-27-fans-blowing-at-full-speed-all-the-time A bit old, but temperature sensor issues after upgrades have always been an issue.

Comment: The new nvme drive is sending temperature information. I can see it with `smartctl`. The older Mac’s required additional sensors built into the  SATA cable from OWC - I own one. This isn’t the case anymore on the later iMacs. I’m still trying to narrow it down.